# After Ready Fading In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am a little bit new to javascript and this may be a really dumb question.

I have a div which fades in on document ready and all i want is that when the box is ready faded in, elements in the div fade after. I can simply increase the fading in timing of the elements but as a programmer it doesn't make that much sense. I tried to used the .ready() method but doesn't seem to work.

Here is a jsFiddle of what i have: `http://jsfiddle.net/Combinu/KmvT3/2/`

```
$('div').fadeIn(1000);

$('div').ready(function () {
     $('label').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to chain them is:

```
$('div').fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $('label').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

The second parameter to [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) is a completion callback.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/KmvT3/15/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').fadeIn(1000,function(){

    $('label').fadeIn(1000);


});
```

reference [fadein](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: This is a bad way to solve the problem. Use a callback like dc5 recommends.

Comment: why u down i am using callback see in the solution @meub

Comment: you are delaying unnecessarily. The first `fadeIn` takes 1000ms  of animation to complete, then the `delay` waits 1000ms then the label takes another 1000ms to fadeIn. The delay just unnecessarily slows down the animation. The completion callback is all you need to solve this problem. make sense?